# Using lat lon position to get data from polygon within shapefile using MapBox?

Tags: shapefile, polygon, mapbox, latitude-longitude

I want to use a dataset of [historical counties](https://discover.ukdataservice.ac.uk/catalogue?sn=4348) and get a parish and county based on a lat lon position.

An extract of the data is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ompf9nqjegcv1ts/par1851.csv?dl=0

The shape data looks like this:

[image]

So the idea is someone selects point on a map (Mapbox), this returns a lat, lon which I then want to use to dynamically return a 'county' and 'parish' based on the data in the csv.

I will need to use a system to determine if the lat, lon is within the area of a parish.

Does anyone has some pointers to get me started?

**UPDATE:**
Created [example](https://codepen.io/r8n5n/pen/GQBMwK) based on Bill's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TURF js, you can determine if your point is inside a polygon. "turf.inside(point, polygon)". Basically using the eachLayer function, you can loop through each poly and determine if the point is inside. If it is turf.inside will return TRUE.

Working example:  The JSON file I used. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/usa.json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js"></script>

<style>  

      #map {
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        z-index: 0;
      }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="map" ></div>
</div>

<script>
var url = 'usa.json';  // my GeoJSON data source, in this case a static file not a live PHP data feed.
//'http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/usa.json' 

    var map = L.map('map').setView([47.7541, -107.05078], 3); 

    var osm=new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{ 
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'});

    var OpenStreetMap_BlackAndWhite = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });
    OpenStreetMap_BlackAndWhite.addTo(map);


// Set style function that sets fill color property
function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: 'green', 
        fillOpacity: 0.5,  
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: '#ffffff',
        dashArray: '3'
    };
}

// Null variable that will hold layer
var stateLayer = L.geoJson(null, { style: style});

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        stateLayer.addData(data);
    });

 stateLayer.addTo(map);

  map.on('click',function(e){  
        lat = e.latlng.lat;
        lon = e.latlng.lng;
        ProcessClick(lat,lon)   
  });

  var theMarker;
  var selPoly = [];

  function ProcessClick(lat,lon){
    if (theMarker != undefined) {
              map.removeLayer(theMarker);
        };
    theMarker = L.marker([lat,lon]).addTo(map);

    stateLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        isInside =turf.inside(theMarker.toGeoJSON(), layer.toGeoJSON());

        if (isInside){
            selPoly.push(layer.feature);
            console.log(layer.feature.properties.STATE_NAME);
        }

    })

    var newgeojsonLayer = L.geoJson(selPoly, {
    color: 'orange',
          fillOpacity: .5,
          opacity: 1
    }).addTo(map);
}

var baseMaps = {
    "Open Street Map": osm,
    "OSM B&W":OpenStreetMap_BlackAndWhite
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "USA":stateLayer
};  
//Add layer control
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, can't find turf.inside, is it now pointsWithinPolygon? http://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon

Comment: Hmm, I found it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/inside and with this script tag: <script src="https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js"></script>  this works.. isInside =turf.inside(theMarker.toGeoJSON(), layer.toGeoJSON());  Not sure why its not shown at the turf site?

Comment: Thanks Bill, really useful. created an example using your code. https://codepen.io/r8n5n/pen/GQBMwK